# Array of NSViews in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

I am working on a Mac application. One of the windows can load several NSView objects that are in the same NIB/XIB file.

But my code looks like this:

```
@interface TheWindowController : NSWindowController {
    //Interface objects
    IBOutlet NSTableView    *detailsTree;
    IBOutlet NSView         *bigView;
    IBOutlet NSView         *subView1;
    IBOutlet NSView         *subView2;
    IBOutlet NSView         *subView3;
    IBOutlet NSView         *subView4;
    IBOutlet NSView         *subView5;
}
```

My question is if that is possible to hold all these IBOutlets inside an Array, Dictionary or something alike. So in the future I could do something like this in my implementation:

```
- (IBAction)traceTableViewClick:(id)sender {
    //having now a NSArray called subviewsArray
    [[[bigView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    [rightView addSubview: [subviewsArray objectAtIndex:[detailsTree selectedRow]]];
}
```

Is it possible? How? Any examples?

Comment: Is `IBOutletCollection` available (I'm iOS only so not sure). `IBOutletCollection(NSView) NSArray *views;`. Then in interface builder connect them up to the collection instead of individual outlets

Comment: `IBOutletCollection` doesn't seem to work on Cocoa's interface builder, it doesn't show in the links section. Super useful in iOS though.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar with a custom view that contains many controls that I want to manipulate en masse.  You need to keep them separate in the `@interface` declaration so that the `IBOutlet` *property* works correctly with Interface Builder, but in your `init` method you can organize them into an array or `NSArray` yourself:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _viewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:subView1, subView2,
                        subView3, subView4, subView5, nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_viewArray release];
    ...etc...
    [super dealloc];
}
```

You can then work on them as you desire:

```
- (void)doThing
{
    for (id view in _viewArray)
    {
        [view doSomething];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your NSViews to a NS(Mutable)Array or a NS(Mutable)Dictionary the same way you would add any other object to them.